# typedef struct with undeclared/undefined type

Tags: c++, c, webrtc

I am reading webrtc source code about VAD, and I am confused about the code

```
typedef struct WebRtcVadInst VadInst;
```

I have searched for all the code about **WebRtcVadInst** and did not find any source related to struct WebRtcVadInst. On the other hand, I did find something about **VadInst**.

```
typedef struct VadInstT_ {
    int vad;
    int32_t downsampling_filter_states[4];
    ...
    ...
    int init_flag;
} VadInstT;
```

and

```
VadInst* WebRtcVad_Create() {
  VadInstT* self = (VadInstT*)malloc(sizeof(VadInstT));

  WebRtcSpl_Init();
  self->init_flag = 0;

  return (VadInst*)self;
}
```

and, it compiles successfully.

How does it work?

Comment: @DavidBowling Oh I did not see the trailing T.:)

Answer (score 5):

The typedef combines a forward declare and a typedef in a single line.

In C++ this could be written

```
struct WebRtcVadInst;            // forward declare a struct

typedef WebRtcVadInst VadInst;   // and introduce an alternate name
```

There is no problem in either language to form a pointer to an unknown struct, as all pointers to structs (and classes in C++) are required to have the same size.

So the code you shown never uses the struct itself (if it even exists) but only a pointer `(VadInst*)`. And that's ok language-wise.